# Hide Print Option in PDF Menu bar using ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, iframe, adobe

I am showing a PDF in iframes. I Want to restrict user to print the PDF using Print option given by Adobe. I have a Custom Print Button and I want the Users to Use that button to print instead of adobe Print option. I'm tracking number of times the PDF was printed. So If they printed using Adobe thing, im not able to track the printed count.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What are you using to display the PDF?

Comment: Using **iframes** to display PDF

Comment: No, you don't. You have the PDF in an iFrame, but this doesn't cause a PDF to render in a browser. How are you referring to the PDF in the document that you are pointing the iFrame to?

Comment: In CS file im giving like this  ** certificateFrameI.Attributes["src"] = PathPDF**

Comment: So, if the user doesn't have a PDF plugin they will end up downloading the file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing in the PDF directly on the iframe `src` attribute (as you indicated in your comments), you do not have *any* control over how the client will render it.

In short, no, you can't control the PDF client and its UI.

Comment: Can we control the print event that was raised by adobe print through javascript?

Comment: @Sid - No. This is done between the browser and the OS and is not exposed to the Javascript engine.